# How to get full screen resolution with Debian?

Tags: debian, xrandr

I have an HP 20wm monitor that I use for programming, which has a resolution of 1600x900. But whenever I try setting the resolution to 1600x900 it gets *cropped* on either side to 1440x900, so when I adjust the monitor setting to full screen it just stretches the image, which looks wrong. `cvt 1600 900` outputs the following:

```
# 1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz
Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```

I set the resolution using `xrandr` as follows:

```
xrandr --newmode "FullScreen"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "FullScreen"
```

This is what I get on either side of the screen:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Even stranger, when I go to `display` under preferences it says 'Resolution 1600 x 900' when that is *clearly* not the case. `xrandr` reveals the following information:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768      60.03 +
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
VGA1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   FullScreen    59.95* 
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Is the mode absent from `xrandr`'s mode list, then? If so, you will probably want to figure out why your GPU driver is not enumerating that mode (EDID issue?). You didn't mention your GPU or graphics driver but I'd suggest trying to switch to the open-source driver if you're using the proprietary one, or vice-versa otherwise.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev Yes, I have to add it. I've plugged my monitor into a laptop. `lspci` outputs the following: `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)`

Comment: Hello bd1251252, did you solve your problem?, please let me know, I am suffering from the same problem. My samsung 900p monitor is showing 1440x900 but the settings on Debian is at 1600x900 with nvidia driver.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot add comments just yet, please consider this as a comment.
Check the syslog, e.g. `dmesg | tail`
Maybe change resolution, check syslog, change bay to virtually correct resolution and check again. Maybe there is something useful.

Comment: Nope not seeing much of anything related to the screen...